# SearchView.isFocused always returns false

Tags: android, widget, android-actionbar, searchview

I'm trying to determine whether a `SearchView` in the ActionBar is focused. But when I call `SearchView.isFocused()` I always get `false` as a result, even when the view is really focused (there is a cursor inside, and the soft keyboard is shown).

How can I check, whether a `SearchView` is focused?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some researching, I learned that `SearchView.isFocused()` always returns `false` because it's some child of the `SearchView` who really has the focus, not the `SearchView` itself. So I use the following code to check the focus of a SearchView:

```
private boolean checkFocusRec(View view) {
    if (view.isFocused())
        return true;

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (checkFocusRec(viewGroup.getChildAt(i)))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So I call `checkFocusRec(searchView)` to check for the focus. I'm not sure this is the optimal solution but it works for me.

Comment: Kotlin extension version:
`val View.hasFocusRec: Boolean
    get() = when {
        isFocused -> true
        this is ViewGroup -> children.any { it.hasFocusRec }
        else -> false
    }`

It requires `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx"`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an ugly (or bug) implementation from SearchView. My suggestion is to extend the SearchView and create methods like so:

```
var isQueryFocused = false
    private set

// you can also override hasFocus() and isFocused() methods, if you prefer
fun hasQueryFocus() = isQueryFocused

override fun setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(listener: OnFocusChangeListener?) {
    super.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        isQueryFocused = hasFocus
        listener?.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus)
    }
}
```

The other answers use recursive calls which is not a very efficient and private resource ID (the inner TextView id) which is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at this question and its [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24082745/1245271), I found some extra information in the resource files included with the Android SDK (in the folder *sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/layout/search_view.xml*).

The subview holding focus has id `@+id/search_src_text` and is of type `android.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete`.

I would therefore suggest the following alternative to the previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24082745/1245271):

```
private boolean isSearchViewFocused(SearchView sview) {
    View et_search =  sview.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    return et_search.isFocused();
}
```